# GRUB boot options in Refind

Tags: 14.04, power-management, macbook-air, refind

I'm trying to lower the power consumption on my Macbook Air with the steps at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir6-2/Trusty#Finetuning_Powersave_functions but I can't seem to get `tlp stat` to show

```
/sys/module/i915/parameters/i915_enable_rc6  =  1 (enabled)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/i915_enable_fbc  =  1 (enabled)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/lvds_downclock   =  1 (enabled)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/semaphores       = -1 (use per-chip default)
```

I've checked that grub.cfg shows these new settings so I suspect that refind isn't using the settings in grub.cfg. I've also read that for refind, you should be able to change the boot options in refind*.conf but I wasn't able to find it.

Also, not sure if this helps but when I boot with GRUB via refind, I get a flashing underscore. So, I boot using one of the vmlinuz options.

Comment: What worked for my MBA6,2 was booting with refind + EFI STUB booting instead of refind+ GRUB and adding the kernel params in the efi stub.